# "As we witness in his correspondence"

Tags: word-meaning

*As we witness in his correspondence, he immediately fell in love with her.*

I am a little bit puzzled by the part "we witness…" I would understand the usage "As the correspondence witnesses…" or "As we can find in his correspondence…" Is this common usage of the verb "witness"?

Comment: I think it's quite common.  see http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/witness?q=witness+  1.1 Have knowledge of (an event or change) from personal observation or experience.

Comment: **Witness** can mean "see for ourselves, observe" and it can be used just like the verb "observe".  *As we observe in these tremors in the earth, the volcano is becoming active once again.*

Answer (score 2):

**Witness** in your example has the meaning of **proof**, based on **fact** and not **interpretation** of circumstances

The author is saying there is **strong objective evidence** the writer immediately fell in love.

The **correspondence** itself can not **witness** (observe) anything since it is **inanimate**, however it can **bear witness** or **lay out the facts** as testimonial in support of a case

"**As we can find in his correspondence…**" could also be used, but the author is emphasising that **subjective judgement** is not necessary since the case is **very strong** in the plain writing

Using **witness** gives it a bit of **legalese** flavour

Comment: I think 'witness' and 'correspondence' deliver a formal tone. We could say 'as we know from his letters'..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand it that on the base of reading the correspondence we'll come to conclusion that he fell in love. So the content of the letters has "the testimonial ability", not "we".

Comment: @StoneyB is quite right +1 , I was referring to the **observational** quality of being a witness, have amended my answer